# Mongoose findOne not working just after save

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using MongoDB version 4.4 with my node project. I am saving a document in the model and just after saving I am reading that document but the result returned from the mongoose query is null.
This works on my local machine but after deploying on AWS this doesn't work.
The configuration versions and all the other things are same as on local and production servers.

Here is the code snippet.

```
var playersActive = mongoose.model("playersOfActiveTable");
var newPlrEnt = new playersActive();
newPlrEnt.channelId = "abcdef";
newPlrEnt.playerId = "qwerty";
newPlrEnt.playerName = "digvijay";
newPlrEnt.playerAmountOnTable = 8542.25;
newPlrEnt.playerState = "SPECTATE";
newPlrEnt.save(function (err, savedValue) {
   if(!err && savedValue){
     console.log("savedResult "+ savedValue);  // print the Document which is saved
     playersActive.findOne({ channelId: "abcdef", playerId: "qwerty" }, function (err, result) {
         console.log("error - "+ err);   // print error - null
         console.log("result - "+ result);  // print result - null
     });
   }else{
     console.log("errror " + err); 
   }
});
```

How can I debug this and solve this issue or what may be the reason for this.

Comment: Is `playersActive` and `plrOfActTbl` same model?

Comment: That is by mistake both are same model, updated here after editing question.

Comment: What is the read preference and write concern being used?

Comment: @Joe No optional parameters used.